# Add parameter to all urls in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on improving a project where currently we have a user `status` parameter stored in session. However, I would like to move `status` out of the session, as I don't want this `status` to be affected by different tabs from the same users. So my proposal is like I need to add the `status` to the end of the URL like

```
htttp://example.com/index/?status=0
```

I already have a before_action for the application controller to read `status` like below

```
 def set_status
    if params[:status]
       @status = params[:status]
    else
       @status = 0
    end
 end
```

Previously, when I stored the status in the session, the before action was more like below

```
 def set_status
    if session[:status].nil?
       session[:status] = 0
    end
    @status = session[:status]
 end
```

But I don't know what to do to add `/?status=0` for all URLs I have in the project and keep it unchanged from one page to another unless the user changes it. As it is a very large and complicated project, I don't think I can go to every view or controller action to manually add it one by one. So I am wondering if there is an elegant solution to it.

Comment: instead of putting the value of status in all urls you could store the value in the database, User model. The very idea of adding it to all urls suggests that it's the wrong approach.

Comment: I don't think that approach applies to my use case. For more details, the same user is allowed to have different statuses crossing different tabs. I would say let's use `workspace` instead of `status` as an example. All the page content loading and modification is based on the current `workspace`. Previously when I store the workspace info in the session, there is an issue when the user change the workspace in one tab, and then the workspace in the other tab is also changed which is not good experience for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to put the workspace as explicit routing parameter, either as a subdomain, or as an initial prefix. So you can have it in all contexts, and keep creating nice URLs.

Comment: Yes.. that is what came to my mind in the first place. However, as we already have another backend service that depends on the current API we build with rails, it might be a huge work to make changes on both sides...